# Using FieldGroup in FieldList causes styling issues, specifically with uploads

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe, fieldset

I have a form in the theme that has two `fieldsets` which I use FieldGroup to do. The field has a document upload area. When I put the upload area into a standard `FieldList` it renders fine with the nice drag and drop area however when it's placed in the `FieldGroup` it loses that formatting:

This has the nice styling:

```
$form = Form::create(
    $this,
    __FUNCTION__,
    FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('Name', 'Name')->setAttribute('required', true)->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name'),
        $doc = new UploadField('Document')
    ),
    FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create('submit', 'Submit')->setAttribute('class', 'btn  btn-success')
    ),
    RequiredFields::create(
        'Name', 'Document'
    )
);
```

But it gets lost in this:

```
$form = Form::create(
    $this,
    __FUNCTION__,
    FieldList::create(
        FieldGroup::create(
            HeaderField::create('Document'),
            TextField::create('Name', 'Name')->setAttribute('required', true)->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name'),
            $doc = new UploadField('Document')
        )
    ),
    FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create('submit', 'Submit')->setAttribute('class', 'btn  btn-success')
    ),
    RequiredFields::create(
        'Name', 'Document'
    )
);
```

Am I using `FieldGroup` correctly?

Comment: I guess you use FieldGroup correctly but UploadField has no styling for inside a FieldGroup. You can you check the classes / css side by side.

Comment: I did, classes inside the upload element are the same but the parents structure is very different, thinking I'll have to write my own template.

Comment: You can set your own template to the FieldGroup by using http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-FormField.html#_setTemplate

Comment: Yeah, wanted to avoid that if possible thats all, seems odd that the addition of a fieldset would change it so much.